# Sql Sever with spring jdbc template

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I need to connect to sql server 2008 and 2012 version with spring jdbc template.

In database, we have column with spaces, I tried with wrapping column which has spaces with `[], ""`, but no use. The following error occurred, when I use a query

```
SELECT Mon, CC Flag FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Msisdn)AS RowNum FROM ME_PREPAID) AS MyDerivedTable WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN 2 AND 100
```

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name
>   'CC'.

Please note that, there is column as `CC Flag`

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you checked .. It might be `CC_Flag`

Comment: @VishalK : The database have a column as `CC Flag`, not `CC_Flag`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found solution for this question. I used like this `[column name]`. It works fine. I already tried like this. But there was a mistake in programming while matching the column names with a list. I used a array list with the values `[Mon],[CC Flag]`.

```
mylist.add="[Mon]";   mylist.add="[CC Flag]";
```

Then I passed this list to the query. When I match the columns name with the list, there was a mistake. The following one is the correct answer.

```
SELECT [Mon], [CC Flag] FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Msisdn)AS RowNum FROM ME_PREPAID) AS MyDerivedTable WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN 2 AND 100
```

Comment: I gave this answer to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can  try this SQL String:

```
String sql = "SELECT Mon, \"CC Flag\" FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Msisdn)AS RowNum FROM ME_PREPAID) AS MyDerivedTable WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN 2 AND 100";
```

Comment: I already tried this, it's not working with spring jdbc template.